# Trying to write a file in c with a function with my main, I can make the file but nothing is in it

Tags: c, function, file

I was able to print in a file but its now stuck in one same result for my `%.4f`. The arrays is not taking the info from my getinfo function and note letting me print the right answer. I am trying to get the duration and directions of a file that gives me the difference from 2 points. I got all the information right but now its just the passing it to the file but it give me bad output in my output file.
For example my read file is :
0,0,0
1,2,3
0,0,0

when i read it and do all the math it gives me the right answer that i am looking for in my getmoveinfo function but when i call the parameter of that function in my writemoveinfo it gets me a different answer which is:
-863204160.0000
-431602080.0000,-431602080.0000,-431602080.0000,-431602080.0000

this is my main:

```
    
    typedef struct Vector Vector;
   struct Vector
   {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    };

    typedef struct MoveInfo MoveInfo;
    struct MoveInfo
    {
    Vector direction;
    float duration;

    };



    int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // add your main function code here
    
    char currentLine[MAX_LENGTH];
    int numLines = 0;
    

    FILE* inputFileName = fopen("points.txt", "r");
    if (inputFileName == NULL)
    {
        printf("file open failed\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (!feof(inputFileName))
    {
        fgets(currentLine, MAX_LENGTH, inputFileName);
        numLines++;
    }

    

    Vector* points = malloc(numLines * sizeof(Vector));

    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        fgets(currentLine, MAX_LENGTH, inputFileName);
        getPointFromString(currentLine, &points[i]);
    }
    fclose(inputFileName);

    


    //read in moveinfo data
    MoveInfo* moveinfo = malloc((numLines-1) * sizeof(MoveInfo));



    /*for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        printf("point %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("%f\n", points[i].x);
        printf("%f\n", points[i].y);
        printf("%f\n", points[i].z);
    }
    */

    int i = 0;
    getMoveInfoBetweenPoints(&moveinfo[i], points[i], points[i + 1]);

    

    FILE* outputfile = fopen("moveinfo.txt", "w");
    if (outputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("file open failed\n");

        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
 
    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {

        writeMoveInfoToFile(&moveinfo[i], outputfile);
    }


        
    

    
    fclose(outputfile);


    
    
    
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

these are  my functions:

```
    int countInputFileLines(char inputFileName[]

    {



     
    int count = 0;


    inputFileName = fopen("points.txt", "r");


    int ch;




    while (EOF != (ch = getc(inputFileName)))
    {
        if ('\n' == ch)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(inputFileName);
    return 0;
}

    void getPointFromString(char string[], Vector* point)


    {
    int commaindex = -1;

    char *result = NULL;

    result = strchr(string, ',');

    char *stringstart = &string[0];

    commaindex = result - stringstart;


    char* numberstring = malloc((commaindex + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(numberstring, string, commaindex);

    numberstring[commaindex] = '\0';

    point->x = atof(numberstring);

    string = &string[0] + commaindex + 1;

    result = strchr(string, ',');

    stringstart = &string[0];

    commaindex = result - stringstart;


    char* Ystring = malloc((commaindex + 2) * sizeof(char));
    
    strncpy(Ystring, string, commaindex);

    Ystring[commaindex] = '\0';
    point->y = atof(Ystring);

    

    /*point->z = string[commaindex + 1];

    char* Zstring = malloc((commaindex + 1) * sizeof(char));

    strncpy(Zstring, string, commaindex);

    Zstring[commaindex] = '\0';

    point->z = atoi(Zstring);

    */

    string = &string[0] + commaindex + 1;

    point->z = atof(string);

    free(numberstring);


    numberstring = NULL;
    free(Ystring);
    Ystring = NULL;
    /*free(Zstring);
    Zstring = NULL;
    */
}

    void getMoveInfoBetweenPoints(MoveInfo* moveInfo, Vector firstPoint, Vector secondPoint)
     {
    float deltax = secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x;
    float deltay = secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y;
    float deltaz = secondPoint.z - firstPoint.z;


    Vector direction;
    direction.x = deltax;
    direction.y = deltay;
    direction.z = deltaz;
    

    float duration= sqrtf(powf(direction.x, 2) + powf(direction.y, 2) + powf(direction.z, 2));

    direction.x /= duration;
    direction.y /= duration;
    direction.z /= duration;

    

    //printf("%.4f\n", duration * 2);
    //printf("(%.4f %.4f %.4f  %.4f )\n ", direction.x, direction.y, direction.z, duration );
}
```

```
void writeMoveInfoToFile(MoveInfo moveInfo[], int count)
{

    int i = 0;
    
    FILE* outputfile;


    
    fprintf(outputfile, "%.4f", moveInfo[i].duration * 2);
    fprintf(outputfile, "%.4f %.4f %.4f %.4f\n", moveInfo[i].direction.x, moveInfo[i].direction.y, moveInfo[i].direction.z, moveInfo[i].duration);
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the file pointer `outputfile` to the function `writeMoveInfoToFile()`, but the function is not getting the file pointer correctly (the argument type if `int` instead of `FILE*` and instead of that a new uninitialized variable `outputfile` is used in the function.

Corrected function:

```
void writeMoveInfoToFile(MoveInfo moveInfo[], FILE* count) /* use correct type */
{

    int i = 0;
    
    FILE* outputfile = count; /* initialize this variable */


    
    fprintf(outputfile, "%.4f", moveInfo[i].duration * 2);
    fprintf(outputfile, "%.4f %.4f %.4f %.4f\n", moveInfo[i].direction.x, moveInfo[i].direction.y, moveInfo[i].direction.z, moveInfo[i].duration);
```

Also note that

```
MoveInfo* moveinfo = malloc(numLines-1 * sizeof(MoveInfo));
```

may not do what you want that to do. The `*` operator has higher precedence than `-` operator, so it will subtract `sizeof(MoveInfO)` from `numLines`.
If you want to allocate `numLines-1` elements of `MoveInfo`, it should be:

```
MoveInfo* moveinfo = malloc((numLines-1) * sizeof(MoveInfo));
```

Comment: it did help print it on the file but now it gives me the same answer for all my %.4f